# MYSQL - Combine 2 tables in one query BUT have 2 WHERE/IN clauses

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am looking to do one MYSQL query on 2 tables and get the results as one object/array. My problem is that the query needs to matcha set of IDs that are named differently in both tables.
Let's say I have a `urls` table and a `products` table and they both have a column that corresponds to the ID I'm searching for but named differently... in the urls table its called resource_id, and in the products table its called productid.

`URLS TABLE:
id  |  resource_id  |  url`

`PRODUCTS TABLE:
productid  |  title  |  description  |  thumbnail`

So in php I have a list of IDs that use to retrieve both tables combined BUT only where the `urls.resource_id` and `products.productid` equal those IDs.

Here is what i have so far:

```
$ids = ["18552", "18554", "18555", "18556"];
$newIds = implode(",",$ids);

$q3 = " SELECT products.title as title, urls.url as url
       FROM urls, products
       WHERE urls.resource_id IN ($newIds)
       AND products.productid IN ($newIds)";
```

At the moment this returns the 4 results based on the `$ids` variable 4 times - 16 results in total. I think it has to do with the `WHERE urls.resource_id IN ($newIds) AND products.productid IN ($newIds` portion of the query since 4 * 4 = 16, but I could be wrong.

Something like this:

```
{ "title": "Prod 1", "url": "prod-one.html" },
{ "title": "Prod 2", "url": "prod-two.html" },
{ "title": "Prod 3", "url": "prod-three.html" },
{ "title": "Prod 4", "url": "prod-four.html" },

{ "title": "Prod 1", "url": "prod-one.html" },
{ "title": "Prod 2", "url": "prod-two.html" },
{ "title": "Prod 3", "url": "prod-three.html" },
{ "title": "Prod 4", "url": "prod-four.html" },

{ "title": "Prod 1", "url": "prod-one.html" },
{ "title": "Prod 2", "url": "prod-two.html" },
{ "title": "Prod 3", "url": "prod-three.html" },
{ "title": "Prod 4", "url": "prod-four.html" },

{ "title": "Prod 1", "url": "prod-one.html" },
{ "title": "Prod 2", "url": "prod-two.html" },
{ "title": "Prod 3", "url": "prod-three.html" },
{ "title": "Prod 4", "url": "prod-four.html" },
```

Not really sure how to achieve this without the repeats... any suggestions?

ALSO - this database is from a shopping cart system so I tried to simplify the example as much as possible without losing clarity in my question/example.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there some common field in urls & products or are they totally unrelated?

Comment: The `resource_id` in the urls table is related to the `productid` in the products table. So in the first ID in the array the  `resource_id` in the urls would be 18552 and the `productid` in the products table would be 18552.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this query. It shows all the entrys that exist in both tables and a in $tdis

```
$ids = ["18552", "18554", "18555", "18556"];
$newIds = implode(",",$ids);

$q3 = " SELECT p.title as title, u.url as url
       FROM urls u INNER JOIN products p ON u. resource_id  = p.productid 
       WHERE u.resource_id IN ($newIds);";
```